# Is it possible to use the selected lines of a one2many list in a function?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Ive been using the module “`web_o2m_delete_multi`” that lets me select multiple lines in `one2many` list view and delete them all.

Is there a way to use the selected lines in a python function? I tried `active_ids` but it’s not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these selected record ids in `ids` instead of `active_ids`.